# Animated TV series or short movie: spaceship filled with red crystals, female android copilot

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, androids

I don't remember too much about it but there was a spaceship that would fill up with ruby red crystals, a human pilot  with a female Android copilot or assistant. It most likely played around the time of Battle of the planets.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never heard of "Battle of the planets".  When did *that* play?  See also [our guidance](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/30482) on asking good story-ID questions.

Comment: Battle of the Planets played from 1978 onwards.  It's an American adaptation/redub of Gatchaman.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you're remembering a scene from *[Starchaser: The Legend of Orin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090065/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*.

The human shoots a rifle penetrating the cargo hold of a crystal hauler and fills his ships cargo hold. The ship is piloted by a bodiless AI. However, the human character does kidnap a female android.